# when i type in input (text type), in livewire, return error in console, not find page (error 400)

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-9, livewires

i installed livewire on laravel 9. and make some text and one input, with  same name. i try to used two way binding. but when i type in input, the screen turns dark, and in console return the error.

POST : http://localhost/livewire/message/test
404
Not Found

my index blade page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
         @livewireStyles
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <livewire:styles />
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Nunito';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">

        @livewire('test')
<script src="{{  url('livewire/livewire.js') }}" >  </script>
   @livewireScripts    
    </body>
</html>
```

the test livewire component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{

    public $text = 'ashy';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.test');
    }
}
```

and the livewire blade code

```
<div>
name : <input type="text" wire:model="text">
<br />
name : {{$text}}
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: What is that livewire.js script tag? It feels like that is a duplicate of the `@livewireScripts` and perhaps that could cause issues. Same goes for `<livewire:styles />`, although that's just CSS and probably won't break anything. Other than that I don't really see anything that could break this.